# Computing Pairwise Distances Through PCA or SVD

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, hierarchical-clustering, svd

What should I do to reduce an mxn (m=17, n=650,000) matrix, where m are samples and n are features of these samples, into a matrix of pairwise distances (which I will then use to generate a dendrogram)?

My idea is to apply SVD (from rsvd https://github.com/erichson/rSVD with k=m) then use the v matrix to compute an mxm pairwise distance matrix. However, whenever I call dist (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/dist) on v, I get a matrix in which each sample is equally distant to the other.

Is it possible to compute pairwise distances by using SVD and what don't I understand about v? and maybe even should I instead be using PCA?

Comment: Could you explain why you prefer to use SVD or PCA (either which could require a great deal of computation) instead of just directly computing the $\binom{17}{2} = 136$ distances directly?

Comment: What I have is genetic data from the lab so I believe that some or even most of those 650k variables could be noise or provide little value to differenating the samples.

Edit:
Also, how to I compute those distances directly?

Comment: The issue of identifying "noise" in this dataset sounds like a very different question than the one you have asked!

Comment: You're probably correct. How would you propose I go about this?

Comment: It depends on what you will use the distances for.  One possibility is to calculate the distances directly and analyze them with a model that incorporates appropriate noise terms in the distances.  The other is to fit the raw data with some kind of dimension-reducing procedure and then compute the distances -- exactly as you propose -- but you don't necessarily have to use SVD/PCA; you might choose something else.

Comment: I want to use the pairwise distances to perform hierachical clustering.

Comment: Why not just directly do that, then?

Comment: That's what I did in the end (just computing the pairwise distances directly), thank you for that. In future, I think it might be worth the effort to explore whether there's something to be gained from methods used in text-document analysis such as SVD or why they're not "working" for this dataset.